# How to use EXISTS to implement business condition

Tags: sql-server

```
create table pat(id int primary key,name varchar(10),address varchar(10))

create table preds(id int primary key,ptext varchar(10),pat_id int foreign key references pat(id))

create table vists(id int primary key,reasn varchar(100),patid int foreign key references pat(id))
```

### --to list all active patients --if atleast one record in visits table --atleast 1 preds record

1. --how to list all unique patients using the view.

---

```
select * from pat where exists(select id from vists v join pat p on v.id=p.patid 
        union 
        select id from preds pr join pat p on pr.patid=p.id
        )
```

Comment: What does the `preds` table contain?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you what you need:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PAT P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT P.ID
    FROM PAT P
    INNER JOIN VISITS V ON P.id = V.patid
    INNER JOIN PREDS PR ON P.id = PR.pat_id
    GROUP BY P.ID
    HAVING (
            COUNT(V.iD) > 1
            AND COUNT(PR.ID) > 1
            )
    ) Patients ON P.ID = Patients.ID
```

Next time I recommend you also post a link to a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) containing the table structures with some sample data, so that we can test and offer a solution much easier/faster.

The version with an implementation of `EXISTS` is:

```
SELECT *
FROM PAT P1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM PAT P
        INNER JOIN VISITS V ON P.id = V.patid
            AND P.id = P1.id
        INNER JOIN PREDS PR ON P.id = PR.pat_id
    GROUP BY P.ID
    HAVING (COUNT(V.iD) > 1 AND COUNT(PR.ID) > 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregates is quite heavy operation as it uses sorting. It is better to use EXISTS, but use JOIN instead:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    pat p
WHERE
    EXISTS ( SELECT
                *
             FROM
                vists v
                JOIN preds pr ON pr.pat_id = v.patid
                                 AND pr.pat_id = p.id );
```